# I have neither grub.conf nor menu.lst

Tags: kernel, configuration, grub2

I just compiled my own kernel for the first time. Because it is mentioned in a tutorial, I now want to check whether the kernel got written into the `grub.conf` file. Well, I did not find a `grub.conf` file. So I googled. Answer: Ubuntu does not have grub.conf, but rather has a `menu.lst` (also stored in `/boot/grub`). So I looked for that file. But I don't have that one either.

So now the question: Where is my GRUB data stored?
I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 with Kernel 2.6.35-27 .

Answer (score 1):

Grub stores its configuration in **`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`**.
This file is generated using the values stored in `/etc/default/grub` via `grub-mkconfig`.

The templates are stored in `/etc/grub.d/`.

If you ever need to manually change something about grub's settings, refer to the `/etc/grub.d/README` file. Meanwhile, you can check if your kernel appears in `grub.cfg` like so:

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep Something
```

Where something is a search query for your kernel's name, like `35-22-generic`.

Answer (score 0):

`/boot/grub/menu.lst` was present in [GRUB legacy](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/grub.html), but [GRUB2 uses](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Changes-from-GRUB-Legacy) `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.